# Click function only working on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a click function that finds hidden buttons with the same class name and clicks them all with one click of another, visible button.

The problem is that it's only running correctly on the second click. On the first click, the it only triggers one hidden button click, not all...

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.mybtn').click(function(){
   var $parent = $(this).closest('.box-half');
   $parent.find(".add-cart").trigger('click');
});
});
```

I've also tried this

```
function myFunction() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.add-cart').forEach(function(el) {
       el.click();
    });
}
document.querySelector('.mybtn').onclick = myFunction;
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I tested this HTML with both of your scripts, and it worked for me. What is your HTML code?

```
<div class="box-half">
    <button class="mybtn">Click mybtn</button>
    <button class="add-cart" style="display:none" id="b1" onclick="console.log(this.id)"></button>
    <button class="add-cart" style="display:none" id="b2" onclick="console.log(this.id)"></button>
    <button class="add-cart" style="display:none" id="b3" onclick="console.log(this.id)"></button>
</div>
```